# Why does my UI Button works in editor but not in android after being built?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, canvas, game-engine

I have an annoying problem with my project on Unity2D. I have created a shop GUI, with buttons to purchase hats.
However, 4 out of the 6 hats buttons are working for some reason in the android build. Whereas for some reason all of them work in editor mode...
They all are in the same Canvas.

For some reason, I moved the button a little bit up, next to the seagull and they seem to be working when I do that. But I want them to work on my shop GUI like the other buttons :X
I don't have anything transparent blocking the buttons by the way (And if I did, it would not work in editor mode as well, right?)

I already tried to
- Move from OnClick() to Event Trigger Pointer Down (no success)
- Change Drag Thresold in the event manager.
- Check Force Active in event manager.
- Redoing the buttons that are not working from scratch...

I'm really clueless, and I need your help!

Some screenshots :

**The Canvas containing my buttons**
[image: The Canvas containing my buttons]

**Green are working buttons, red are not working, and orange is selected (work in editor) see bottom right corner**
[[image: Green are working buttons, red are not working, and orange is selected (work in editor) see bottom right corner][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI8Es.png)

[image: The poop button which is not working]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You should add images using img tag or clicking our image icon

Comment: Do the buttons boundaries (clickable area) match up with the image size?

Comment: you should stick to the `OnClick`. Can you make sure to method is not called at all or maybe only misbehaving somehow? E.g. print out Debug.Log and display the console log on the screen

Comment: tramada,thank you!
I already uploaded image onto my main post? Sorry I'm kind of new.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/50OqJ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI8Es.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1yOn.png
I can add more images if you wish to see something in my inspector, let me know!

MSvenTorjusC1999, by buttons boundaries, do you mean the anchors? I did made them as close as possible to the image size.

@derHugo I haven't seen any difference going from OnClick to Event Trigger, but I will go back to Onclick then. I'm going to add text printing Debug.Log to see if the method is called. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reasons try placing your button as the lowest index siblings in the hierarchy so that no other UI element overlaps them.
Secondly try using reference resolution as 1080 X 1920 with match factor as 0.5

Comment: Thank you so much, for some reason, placing the elements at the lowest index sibling in my canvas actually worked. I have no idea why though since the others elements were not on top of my buttons, but oh well, at least it works fine now!